# Using ember.js with node.js + express.js

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js

After years of PHP/MySQL development on the server-side, I'm trying to explore new technologies for building modern web applications.

I'm trying to make an order between all the JavaScript stuff and, if I have understood well, a valid solution can be node.js on the server-side, express.js to handle routing and, for example, ember.js and/or knockout.js to handle client-side with MVC/MVVM, binding, observers. Is it a valid architecture?

Comment: yes, but be careful with client-side frameworks -- you might not get indexed by Google.

Comment: aren't ember and express both libraries that do the same thing?

Answer (score 7):

I built a pretty straightfoward website at the following github location

https://github.com/bwship/neptunejs

It uses node for the server side and ember for the clientside.  It is also using Parse.com for it's data and api layer.  But, the general idea should all be layed out for you there, including what I feel is a pretty solid folder and file structure.

Let me know if you have any questions.  I came from an ASP.NET background, and have just completely fallen in love with client-side MVC.

Comment: thank you, good sir!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Here's hoping you just drastically eased the learning curve.

Comment: Sure thing @RalphMarczynski  Note that this is using an old ember implementation, so the controllers are static the router is old etc.  I do plan on upgrading this to the new ember RC stuff, but just have not gotten a chance.